# npm install ws doesn't work

Tags: installation

I want to implement a websocket server in node.js. For that I want to install 'ws'. I've already installed npm and node.js in my ubuntu system. Now I'm trying to run the command 'sudo npm install ws' but it doesn't work. I'm pasting the content of my terminal. Can someone help?

```
root@Neeraj:/home/neeraj# npm install ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: ws
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-    client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:209:10)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/tunnel.js:164:21)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/neeraj/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "ws"
npm ERR! cwd /home/neeraj
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: ws
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/neeraj/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
root@Neeraj:/home/neeraj#
```

Answer (score 0):

This post solved [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/installing-from-npm-fails), as easy as establishing the npm registry with

```
 npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Anyway, thanks!